# Filter DataFrame if group of indexes have the same value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset which are lines of journal entries (accounting debit/credit entries)

```
Entry   Debit   Credit   Account
 1        1                 A
 1                1         B

 2        2                 A
 2                1         C
 2                1         C

 3        4                 C
 3                1         G
 3                1         A
 3                1         D
 3                1         K

 4        1                 H
 4                1         J
```

As you can see we just have 4 journals as they are identified by the Entry Number (Index).

What I need is to filter all Journals that contain Account A, not each line that contains A. The problem is if I do it by account I just get the line that has Account A but I lose the other line related that not necessarily will use Account A.

So after the filter is applied, I should get something like this:

```
Entry   Debit   Credit   Account
 1        1                 A
 1                1         B

 2        2                 A
 2                1         C
 2                1         C

 3        4                 C
 3                1         G
 3                1         A
 3                1         D
 3                1         K
```

Account 4 will not be displayed because there's no Entry (index) containing account A.

Setup:

```
d = {'Entry': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0, 7: 3.0, 8: 3.0, 9: 
3.0, 10: 3.0, 11: 3.0, 13: 4.0, 14: 4.0}, 
 'Debit': {0: 1.0, 1: np.nan, 3: 2.0, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 7: 4.0, 8: np.nan, 
           9: np.nan, 10: np.nan, 11: np.nan,13: 1.0, 14: np.nan}, 
 'Credit': {0: np.nan, 1: 1.0, 3: np.nan, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 7: np.nan,
            8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 
            11: 1.0, 13: np.nan, 14: 1.0}, 
 'Account': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 7: 'C', 8: 'G', 
           9: 'A', 10: 'D', 11: 'K', 13: 'H', 14: 'J'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: It appears the you need a `groupby` to get each journal taken as a unit, then an `any` operation to look for the desired account.  Can you post your coding attempt and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pandas Groupby` provides you with a `filter` mechanism which takes in a subset of dataframe/group and the `filterfunction`

A particular subset of data will be selected if the `filterfunction` is **True** and will be dropped if not.

In your case, you want to select the row's where for every (group) `Entry` (index) there exists `A` in **Account**

So, our `filterfunciton` will become can be set to
`lambda grp: grp['Account'].isin(['A']).any()`

For the give data,

```py
df.groupby(['Entry']).filter(lambda grp: grp['Account'].isin(['A']).any())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` with `any` here:

```
df[df['Account'].eq('A').groupby(df['Entry']).transform('any')]
#or df[df['Account'].eq('A').groupby(level=0).transform('any')] if Entry is index
```

---

```
    Entry  Debit  Credit Account
0     1.0    1.0     NaN       A
1     1.0    NaN     1.0       B
3     2.0    2.0     NaN       A
4     2.0    NaN     1.0       C
5     2.0    NaN     1.0       C
7     3.0    4.0     NaN       C
8     3.0    NaN     1.0       G
9     3.0    NaN     1.0       A
10    3.0    NaN     1.0       D
11    3.0    NaN     1.0       K
```